# when making ajax calls on submit click, do you need forms?

Tags: html, ajax

I have a page that will display a search form with 3 fields, and a submit button. 
when the user clicks on submit, i'm going to make an ajax call, get the data, and then populate the bottom half of the page. 
What I'm wondering is if you're using ajax calls, would you still create the form using the  tag? 
So for example, here's some sample HTML:

```
<H2> Search Options</H2>
<DIV ID="searchform" class="">
        <input type='text' id='id'></input>
        <input type='text' id='firstname'></input>
        <input type='text' id='lastname'></input>
                    <input type='button' id='submit'></input>
</DIV>
```

as you can see, I don't have a  tag with post attrib set. 
can you tell me why i should / shouldn't include the form tag while using ajax? 
Thanks.

Comment: Great Question! I was just wondering the same thing. I am making a Ajax Post Request on Submit for my website and I was just wondering if the HTML tags surround the parameters needed to be in a Form. This answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it at all.

The only problem comes when a user doesn't have JavaScript enabled. How will your form behave then?

Comment: good point.  i totally forgot about that.  in my case, i can control the user's env because this is a corporate env.  but... nonetheless, something I didn't think of. thanks for the reminder. So if i want it to be bullet proof, i should add the form, change the default behavior of a form's submit button via jscript and then do the ajax from there eh?  although if they have jscript turned off, then this whole thing bombs regardless because it's javscript that loops through the search results and displays them on page...

Comment: If JavaScript is forced then you don't necessarily need the form. But it is a good practice to get into!

Answer (score 1):

***Assuming javascript is enabled in client's browser**

If you are handling Ajax call on button click event, then no need of using `<form />`.

Because each fields you'l get in javascript by using `document.getElementByID` or some other mechanism (JQuery selectors). moreover the Ajax call also you are making manually so you can avoid use of `<form />`.

Using `<form />` will just add few bytes overhead to html page, there isn't any other advantage of using `<form/>` in this case, **if you are handling ajax call on button Click event.**

Comment: yes.  that's exactly what I'm doing.  i did see other examples of people who are using the form, and then on form submit click event, they run a javascript function that then does the .post for them.  any comments on which way is better?

Comment: My suggestion is don't use <form/>
if everything is handled manually by .post, then we can simply avoid that extra overhead to page and make page load faster for the user. Taking care of few bytes are also important in a large application.:)

Comment: Thanks Ravi.  +1 for you too!